# Копирование контейнеров

Tags: c++, stl

```
template<class In, class Out> void copy(In from, In too_far, Out to)
{
    *to = *from; //копируем элемент указуемый итератором
    ++to; // следующий выходной элемент
    ++from; //следующий входной элемент
}

char vc1[200];
char vc2[200];

void f1()
{
    copy(&vc1[0], &vc1[200], &vc2[0]);
}

std::complex<double> ac[200];

void g(std::vector<std::complex<double>> &vc, std::list<std::complex<double>> &lc )
{
    copy(&ac[0], &ac[200], lc.begin());
    copy(lc.begin(), lc.end(), vc.begin())
}
```

Код взят из книги и отредактирован для использования со стандартными контейнерами, вместо собственных классов.
Ошибка:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0308   more than one instance of function template "copy" matches the argument list:   ClassesAndMore  c:\Users\Dima\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ClassesAndMore\ClassesAndMore\Template.h    73  
Error (active)  E0308   more than one instance of function template "copy" matches the argument list:   ClassesAndMore  c:\Users\Dima\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ClassesAndMore\ClassesAndMore\Template.h    72
```

Со стандартной библиотекой работал очень мало.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Здесь срабатывает правило языка, называемое [Argument Dependent Lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) (ADL) — поиск, зависимый от аргументов. Заключается оно в том, что при поиске функции рассматривается не только текущее пространство имён, но и пространство имён аргументов функции. В случаях когда типы аргументов находятся в `std`, т.е. для `ac` и `lc`, обнаруживается функция `std::copy`. Если нужно вызывать только вашу шаблонную функцию, можно явно указать глобальное пространство имен, т.е. вызывать так:

```
::copy(lc.begin(), lc.end(), vc.begin());
```

Еще должен сработать такой вариант:

```
(copy)(lc.begin(), lc.end(), vc.begin());
```

Comment: Что значат скобки, в (copy)?

Comment: @димасоколов преобразует функцию в выражение, что блокирует работу ADL. Пример есть по упомянутой ссылке.

Answer (score 2):

Функция `copy` перегруженна и компилятор не может выбрать какая реализация подходит лучше для аргументов передающихся в нее, ваша или [copy из стандартной библиотеки](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/). Решение – переименовать вашу `copy`, либо вовсе не перегружать ее.

Comment: Спасибо. А как это произошло? Ведь при использовании стандартной библиотеки, нужно писать using namespace std; или вызывать функцию явно указывая область видимости std::copy()

Comment: @димасоколов у вас подключен заголовочный файл algorithm?

Comment: Да, но он possibly unused